# How to describe the roughness of a function?

Tags: real-analysis

For the simplist case, there are two functions:
$$
f(x) = \sin(x) 
$$

$$
g(x) = \sin(x) + \frac{1}{5} \sin(20x) 
$$
and their curves look like:
[image]

We can have intuitively sense that $g(x)$ curve is more rough than $f(x)$. But this feel is a little bit difficult to be quantitively described in Mathematics. I'm wondering is there a quantity that can describe the roughness of a function?

And even forward, can we describe the **global roughness** and **local roughness** of a function curve?

The global roughness, by literally, should describe the roughness of a function over all space.

However, the local roughness should be able to describe the roughness of a function on a given interval. And the local roughness value will vary as the interval changes. If the interval is infinitesimal, then the roughness of a continuous smooth function should be zero.

I know that there are many definitions of roughness in physics. But, these definitions maybe not suitable. Just consider $Ra$ in [this page](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Surface_roughness#:%7E:text=Surface%20roughness%20can%20be%20regarded,it%20is%20a%20multiscale%20property), we have:
$$
Ra_f(x) = \frac{1}{x} \int_0^{x} |f(x)| dx 
$$

$$
Ra_g(x) = \frac{1}{x} \int_0^{x} |g(x)| dx 
$$

From our previous considersion, the roughness $Ra_g(x)$ should larger than $Ra_f(x)$ for $x>0$. But if we set $x=4$, we can get $Ra_f(x)=0.59$ and $Ra_g(x)=0.09$, which is not what we expected.

Comment: There seems to be lots of formulae [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_roughness#:~:text=Surface%20roughness%20can%20be%20regarded,it%20is%20a%20multiscale%20property).

Comment: @sreysus thanks for the information. The roughness in physics can do partially define the 'local roughness'. But the calculated roughness for $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ in my question maybe wrong sometimes.

Comment: I don't really understand how those formulae represent roughness at all. They're just running averages of the absolute value. So they are in particular nonzero for constant functions. One "very global" way to define roughness is to take some $L^p$ norm of the difference between the function and its average value. But this will not tell you that low amplitude high frequency oscillations are "rough".

Comment: Maybe something involving  $\int_{B}^\infty\, |F(k)|^2\,dk$ where $F$ is the Fourier transform of $f$?